# How to write a simple get method api Using node and webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

can I use `web pack dev server` to write api's ? If yes could somebody give me some code examples ? thank's in advance.

Comment: Had a look at [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#api) ?